# Film Age (unsure if i should risk it)

Tags: film

If I use film from the 1980s that was put into the freezer ever since it was bought by my great grandfather, will it still work?

Comment: Why not try one roll?  It won't cost a lot of money to develop & examine the negs.

Comment: @scottbb I also remember that question, but I'm unsure if the freezing of the film would make it a different question.

Answer (score -1):

It will produce *some kind of images*, but they will be super low-contrast, and have a bizarre color palette. Film is somewhat sensitive to light outside the visible spectrum. Film this old has been slowly exposed by some of this light. So imagine parts of the film that are supposed to produce black (the film base). Instead of producing black, now they will produce a lighter, tinted color rather than black. That base tint will also throw off all the other colors in the images. So yes, it will "work," but not very well, unless you like bizarre results. Having worked in the photographic industry for 30 years, I've seen this played out many times.

According to a [Popular Photography article](http://www.popphoto.com/guide-to-shooting-expired-film) I found:

> Over time, the sensitivity of the silver halides can begin to
>   degrade. Cosmic and background radiation (as well as fallout from
>   nuclear testing) may also cause the unmodified silver salts to be
>   modified in random—and usually somewhat even—distribution, which
>   reduces the number of available unexposed crystals and introduces
>   noise. This is called fogging.

Comment: The internet cliche here is " [citation needed]" . The point is that it's perfectly possible that the emulsions have not aged significantly.  Your claim about gamma rays is just plain false.

Comment: Claims my statement is false and needs citation. Provides no citation that my claim is false. Hmm...

Comment: "Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof." The refutation of a claim is not where the burden of proof rests. Most of the time,  marginally aged film will be just fine.

Comment: It's hardly an extraordinary claim to say that near-30 year-old film will exhibit fogging beyond marginal. I've literally seen it happen many times in my years in the photo industry. I would posit that it's more extraordinary to claim that near-30 year-old film is "marginally aged."